# Is it necessary to add "do it" in the following case?

Tags: ellipsis

> My headache was so bad by then I could barely go to class. And when I
>    managed to **do it**, I couldn't listen to the professor at all.

Can I just write, "*And when I managed to, I couldn't...*"?

Comment: I'd use "do so", but I don't think omitting is problematic. Still, that's a thought. I'm waiting for answers, just like you.

Comment: I think it's alright to drop "do it" in that sentence.

Comment: Interestingly, you can even leave out the "to", in a phrase like "and when I finally managed" or "and when I did manage", but not "and when I managed".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. The **to** in "*And when I managed to, I couldn't...*" links to `verb` in the preceding sentence, which is **go**. So, when you say "*And when I managed to, I couldn't...*" the *to* acts as a **to-infinitive** for **to go** and thus it actually means "*And when I managed to* ***go***, *I couldn't...*". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that **it** sounds wrong.  It should be either "to," or "to do so,".

So, not only can you do so, I would say you should do so.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** It is not necessary, you can leave out "do it".

> My headache was so bad by then I could barely go to class. And when I managed to, I couldn't listen to the professor at all.

In the second sentence above, 'to' acts as a [pro-verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb), which is like a [pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun), but for verb phrases.

That Wikipedia article includes this explanation and example:

> Since a to-infinitive is just the particle 'to' plus a bare infinitive, and a bare infinitive can be elided, the particle 'to' doubles as a pro-verb for a to-infinitive:
>
> Clean your room! —I don't want to [clean my room].
>      He refused to clean his room when I told him to [clean his room].